# get data from external url after sending file using ajax and python

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, wordpress

```
<form  id="myForm" method="post" name="myForm">         NDA DOC: <input type="file" name="file1">
         <input type="submit"  id="submit">
      </form>
```

thats the js

```
   $('#myForm').submit(function(e){
                          e.preventDefault();
        let data = $( this ).serialize()
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://www.example.com/uploader",
            data: data,
            success: function(response){
              // success action here
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(response) {
              // error action here
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
```

this code in wordpress site
i'm getting this error
(index):1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://www.example.com/uploader' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: You can't read the data from an xmlhttprequest to a different domain. The owner of example.com would have to add a specific header to his response to allow you to read it on your domain

Comment: i've fixed this issue now getting this error  :jquery.min.js:2 GET http://www.example.com/uploader?callback=jQuery331012350436225395778_1550277346166&_=1550277346167 net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)

Comment: That's mean your not fixed the issue. Even the browser itself doesn't allow you to do cross request read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS